# stop service when my app is not running in background

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I want to check new messages every 10 mins in the background using alarmManager/Service(I have written the code for the same) but since service runs even if the app is alive or dead .I want the service to stop if app is not running in the background .How do I do this ?

Please Help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop your service on the onPause state of your activity.

Visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html for more details about services.

For AlarmManager visit http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html for more deailts. There you can find cancel method to remove any alarm that matches your intent.

Comment: if it stops at onPause() then it will not update in the background when you press home button right ?

Comment: Yes. It is a usual practice to start your service in onResume and stop in onPause.

You can read the activity life cycle of android activity in more details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: I would like to stop service onDestroy() how do I stop the service?

Comment: Have you read the life cycle activity of an android activity? It is not guaranteed that onDestroy is called by the system.

To stop the service call stopService(intent). Read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)

Comment: instead of stopping the service I am using cancel(pending intent) when user exits the app.Is that good ?

Comment: Yup, since you are using the AlarmManager right? cancel method will turn off or cancel scheduled alarm :)